# How to count the occurrences of a value on a dataframe and plot it while considering the time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this but much larger:

```
title of the novel                author          publishing year   mentionned cities   
0   Beasts and creatures        Bruno Ivory             1850           New York 
0   Monsters                    Renata Mcniar           1866           New York 
0   At risk                     Charles Dobi            1870           New York   
0   Manuela and Ricardo         Lucas Zacci             1889           New York
0   War against the machine     Angelina Trotter        1854           New York
```

My objective is to create a line chart that shows the decades in which the city (in this case, "New York") was mentioned in a novel. I have tried several things, as you can see in a previous post about the same problem. I thought I had solved it, but I did not.

([How to count the occurrences of a value in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929307/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-value-in-a-data-frame/72929773#72929773))

Here is an image I made in Excel. This should exemplify the desired outcome.[image]

Update:

Someone tried to help me, but deleted the answer. Fortunately, I had gotten it already. However, I did not work.

I think the code is worth mentioning:

```
counts = df[['publishing year', 'mentionned cities']].value_counts().reset_index(name='counts').sort_values('publishing year')
counts[counts.mentionned cities == 'New York'][['publishing year', 'counts']].set_index('publishing year').plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby.count()` then use `Series.plot()`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axes = df.groupby('publishing year')['title of the novel'].count().plot()
axes.set_ylim(0, 5)
axes.set_xlabel('19th Century')
axes.set_ylabel('Number of novels')
axes.set_title('City of New York')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but this is not exactly what I had asked for, as you can see in the image. Can someone help me, please?